# Every irreducible element is prime: always holds under surjective ring homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, unique-factorization-domains

Let $f:R\rightarrow S$ be a surjective ring homomorphism. $R,S$ are both integral domains.

> If every irreducible element in $R$ is prime, then is it true that every irreducible element in $S$ is prime?

How about the converse:

> If every irreducible element in $S$ is prime, then is it true that every irreducible element in $R$ is prime?

Comment: Do you not require "integral domain" to talk about irrducible elements?

Comment: I want to study some preserving properties under this homomorphism. I only consider the case in integral domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are false. Consider the ring homomorphisms:
$$\mathbb Z[x]\xrightarrow{\varphi}\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2+5)=\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]\xrightarrow{\psi} \mathbb Z/(5)$$

The homomorphism $\varphi$ is the map given by taking the quotient by the indicated ideal. The homomorphism $\psi$ can be constructed as follows. Start with the mapping $\mathbb Z[x]\to\mathbb Z/(5)$ that maps any polynomial $f(x)$ to the congruence class of $f(0)$ mod. $5$. We note that $x^2+5$ maps to $0$, so that the ideal $(x^2+5)$ is a subset of the kernel of this mapping. Taking the quotient by this ideal, we obtain $\psi$.

Since every ring here is Noetherian (cf. Hilbert's Basis Theorem), they are UFDs if and only if every irreducible is prime. However, as in Example 1.8 [here](http://math.harvard.edu/~waffle/ufds2.pdf), $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ is not a UFD. Both $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are surjective, while $\mathbb Z/(5)$ and $\mathbb Z[x]$ are UFDs.

Comment: $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]\xrightarrow{\psi} \mathbb Z$ cannot be a ring homomorphism, see the linked question.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you! It is always humbling to see what sorts of errors I am susceptible to. Thankfully the conclusion I draw (both are false) holds despite my flawed reasoning, with only a slight modification.